# .htaccess Allow owner of home directory only?

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, .htaccess, users, home-directory

Suppose I have a home directory "~someuser/www" which Apache (maintained by someone else than me) exposes as http://www.myserver.com/~someuser . If I want to limit this directory to certain users, I can create a .htaccess file in the www folder containing the line "Require user username1 username2" etc.

The question is: Is there a way to specify in .htaccess that only the owner of the home directory, whoever that might be, is supposed to be able to access it from the web?

If I knew that the owner was "someuser", then I would just specify "Require user someuser", but in this case I'm trying to put together a template that will work for a lot of users, and I'd like to avoid having to tell them each to insert their own username if possible.

(More background: Specifically I'm trying to get it to work on the MIT site described here: http://scripts.mit.edu/faq/15 . We'll have students doing little web projects in their own www folders, but don't want other students to be able to view their JavaScript source code.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a cop-out, but make the students do it:

Make your first-day-getting-familiar-with-the-lab exercise something that gets this kind of housekeeping set up, explaining what the `.htaccess` file is, and linking the students to the [.htaccess tutorial](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html).  Then as one of the exercises have them restrict web access on **some directory** to themselves, the TAs and the professor.

This is what I've traditionally done for the first-year programming classes I occasionally run at my alma mater ("Set the permissions on your home directory so people can't snoop.", "Configure CVS/git/whatever for your account." , etc...) - It saves me the work of having to do it, and makes the students get comfortable with the environment they'll be working in.

Comment: You can probably also do some hackery with SetEnv and URL parsing (though I don't know that you can do it in .htaccess - it may need to be done in the main apache config file) -- I would actually have to sit down and play to figure that out though.  It strikes me as "Probably possible, but definitely work."

Comment: Not unreasonable. In the end I created the file with the right user name as part of a script that they had to run to set up their system in the first place. Thanks!